# CSS <a> tag is longer than the image inside it?

Tags: html, css

I was inspecting the elements on firefox and chrome I realised that the `a` element is longer than the image inside it. The image is 102px and the `a` is 106.4px. I'm wondering where do the extra 4.4 pixels come from?

The original image is 102px by 102px.

[image: Image Size Screenshot]

[image: a tag Size Screenshot]

here's my code (also on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g5nsL52a/ ):

```css
header {
 min-height:102px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family: "Felix Titling Regular", Times, serif;
}
header a {
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
}

header h1 {
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 top:29px;
 font-size:300%;
 text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/430205/pexels-photo-430205.jpeg" width="102" height="102" alt="Godfather Logo" title="Godfather Small Logo"/>
  </a>
  <h1> loyal capos to the don </h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image

Comment: @RauliRajande Got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
header a{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    height:102px;
    width:102px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Could you update your answer and explain what you are doing. Many thanks in advance

Comment: other tag css tag <a> properties (css) override so change css and I'm give static width and height  <a> tag with css.
You're welcome.